# Socket send and get txt file c

Tags: c, sockets

So I have a server.c and a client.c
The client.c will prompt to enter a file name, then send the file name to server and check if the file is exist, if yes send that file to client.
My problem is that when the server get correct file name and send to client, the client cannot receive the file.

here is the server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>   
#include<string.h>   
#include<unistd.h>    
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<pthread.h> 

#define PORT 5000

void *multiconnection(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int s_sock , c_sock;
int sin_size; 
int *addSocket;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in client;

/* initial */
s_sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (s_sock < 0)
{
    perror("socket cannot be created");
}
printf("Socket is successfully created\n");

/* Fill the socket address struct */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

/* Bind a special Port */
if(bind(s_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("binding Error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("binding success\n");

/* Listen to connect */
listen(s_sock , 3);

/* Accept connections */
printf("Waiting clients connections:::\n");

sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while((c_sock = accept(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&sin_size)) )
{
    /* create new sockets for mulitiple clients */
    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    addSocket = malloc(1);
    *addSocket = c_sock;

    if( pthread_create(&sniffer_thread,NULL, multiconnection,(void*) addSocket) < 0)
    {
        perror("Threads error");
        exit(1);
    }
}

if (c_sock < 0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
}


void *multiconnection(void *s_sock)
{
/* Get the socket descriptor */
int sock = *(int*)s_sock;
int read;
char *msg , c_msg[2000];

/* Receive a message from client */
while(read = recv(sock , c_msg , sizeof(c_msg) , 0) > 0 )
{
printf("Recieve file name from client: %s\n", c_msg);
if (fopen(c_msg,"r") == NULL)
    write(sock , "File does not exsit" , 20);
else
{
    write(sock ,"File exsit", 20);
    /* if file exsit, send to clients  */
        char* file_pth = "/home/nelson/Desktop/SYSPROG_asg_04A_Tang/hello.txt";
    char buff[1024]; 
        printf("Sending %s to the Client...\n", file_pth);
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_pth, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        {
        perror("Open file error");
    exit(1);
    }

    int file_size; 
    while(file_size = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff), fp) > 0)
    {
    if(send(sock, buff, file_size, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fail to send file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Buff : %s",buff);
    }
        write(sock , "You Recieved the file" , 50);
    printf("file is sent to client!\n");
        //close(sock);
}   
}

if(read < 0)
     perror("fail to recieve");


free(s_sock);

return 0;
}
```

Here is my client.c, now i am just trying to get the content from the text file, but it cannot.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<string.h>   

#define PORT 5000
#define localAddr "127.0.0.1"
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int s_sock;
char msg[512];
char reply_msg[512];
char buff[512]; 
struct sockaddr_in server;

/* initial */
s_sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

if (s_sock < 0)
{
    perror("socket cannot be created");
}
printf("Socket is successfully created\n");

/* Fill the socket address struct */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(localAddr);

/* Connect to server */

if (connect(s_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("connection error");
    //exit(1);
}

printf("Connected\n");

while(1)
{
    printf("Enter file name you wish to get from server: ");
    scanf("%s" , msg);

    /* send file name */
    if(send(s_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Sending error");
        //exit(1);
    }

    /* Receive message from sever */
    if( recv(s_sock,reply_msg , 512 , 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Receive message error");
        //exit(1);
    }

    printf("Server reply : %s\n",reply_msg );


    /* Receive a file */
if (strcmp(reply_msg,"File exsit") == 0)
    {
   //memset(reply_msg, 0, sizeof(reply_msg));
       printf("Receiving file from Server\n");
   char* file_path = "/home/nelson/Desktop/SYSPROG_asg_04A_Tang/final.txt";
   FILE *fp = fopen(file_path, "a");

   if(fp == NULL)
    printf("File %s Cannot be opened.\n", file_path);

   char buff[512];
   //recv(s_sock,buff , sizeof(buff) , 0);
        printf("buff : %s\n", buff);
    printf("buff : %s\n", reply_msg);
   /*int w_size = fwrite(reply_msg, sizeof(char), sizeof(reply_msg), fp);
   if(w_size < sizeof(reply_msg))
   {
       perror("Writing error.\n");
   }

   if (sizeof(reply_msg) == 0 || sizeof(reply_msg) != 512) 
   {
       break;
   }
   if(sizeof(reply_msg) < 0)
       {
       perror("error");
   }
   printf("Ok received from server!\n");
   fclose(fp);     */
    }else
    printf("\n");
    }

close(s_sock);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean: "*the client cannot receive the file*", please be specific. Did you write all the code, or did you take parts of it from someone else? I ask that because there is no clear coding style in your code so it appears like more than one person worked on it.

Comment: At least some of the usual suspects: 'printf("Recieve file name from client: %s\n", c_msg);' : calling  printf("%s.....' on a buffer that is not guaranteed NULL-terminated.  Failing to correctly and completely handle the results of system calls, especially recv().  Assuming that a TCP stream can transfer messages longer than one byte without a protocol on top.  Assuming that recv() always loads the number of bytes requested by its arguments into the buffer.

Comment: 'addSocket = malloc(1);' does not allocate enough space for the int fd 'c_sock'.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162279/758133

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when the server get correct file name and send to
>   client, the client cannot receive the file.

The basic cause of this problem is of course that you commented out the `recv()` call in the client:

```
   //recv(s_sock,buff , sizeof(buff) , 0);
```